# Parse HTML and Javascript with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

let say i have html like this and will requested with ajax :

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="main">
            <div class="content"></div>
            <script>
            $(".content").doaction();
            </script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

is it possible to get (parse) #main including javascript tag & content inside it with jquery?

thank you!

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to get (parse) #main including javascript tag & content inside it with jquery?

Not easily - jQuery is pretty bad at handling text nodes.

You *can* use `$('script').contents()` to get just the script, but there's no easy way to build a nested object containing elements *and* text nodes all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You can fire the `$(".content").doaction()` right in the success callback of the Ajax load.

I have never seen a working example of a nested JavaScript after the ajax load.